How to use VS Extensibility access Forms Designer's current Form properties?
I'm writing a Visual Studio 2022 Extensibility add-in using VB.Net/DotNetFramework in which I'd like to read and write the individual Properties of a Windows Form that is currently being Designed in the IDE's Forms Designer. Any suggestions or examples on how to access these properties?
